# How can I create a new folder in my web-app (for upload photo album) with Grails on Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

i want to create a photo album. 
But I want to organize on the server the albums so I want to create new folders :

/myapp
/myapp/albums
/myapp/albums/1
/myapp/albums/2
...

How can I do that on tomcat with Grails ? It create all new folder in tomcat/bin not in tomcat/webapps/myapp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't do Grails, but since it runs on top of the Servlet API, you may find this answer (a steering in the right direction) useful as well.

First, get a handle of the [`ServletContext`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html). Normally you would use the `GenericServlet`-inherited [`getServletContext()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletContext%28%29) method for this. Then make use of the [`ServletContext#getRealPath()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) method to convert a *relative web path* to an *absolute local disk file system path* (because that's the only which `java.io.File` reliably understands).

```
String absolutePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("albums/1");
File file = new File (absolutePath);
// ...
```

If you use relative paths in `java.io.File` stuff, then it will become relative to the current working directory which depends on the way how you startup the server and which indeed may be `Tomcat/bin` as you experienced yourself.

That said, there's another major problem with this approach: if you create folders in an exploded webapp, they will **get lost** whenever you redeploy the webapp or even restart the server! Rather create folders outside the webapp's context, in a fixed path somewhere else at the disk file system. Or if you want better portability (but poorer metadata information), then consider storing it in a database instead.

Comment: Thanks. Effectively, I restart often the server and I don't want loose my files. 
But thanks a lot for your answer, it's more clear.

Answer (score 6):

When I had to do something similar I defined a root path in my Config.groovy like

```
environments {
    production {
rootPath="/home/user/reports"
    }
    development {
rootPath="c:\\reports"
    }
    test {
rootPath="c:\\reports"
    }
```

Then create a directory like the following.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder as Conf
tempFile=new File(Conf.config.rootPath+"dirName")
tempFile.mkdir()
```

Comment: Thanks it's probably the best way at this time for my app